# Juju Openstack - manual modifications to code are overwritten

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I want to make permanent changes to Openstack code that is installed via Landscape/Autopilot. Is there a way to disable hooks from overwriting these changes?

Comment: Can you give an example of a file that you want to edit? Some files wont be overwritten by charm hooks anyway.

Comment: I was referring to good ol' nova.conf, along with other config files. I changed tack and focused on patching upstream charms and abandoned Autopilot entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach is to use the charms deploy-from-source configuration and point them at branches you maintain with your patches.

Comment: You mean I'd have to maintain a separate branch for the Autopilot cloud-installer?

Comment: I abandoned Landscape/Autopilot. I instead patch upstream charms with my customized .conf and .ini files. This worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

A hacked up approach would be to make the changes in

> /var/lib/juju/agents/unit-charmname-unitnumber/charm/

This way the hooks wont overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in facility for this.  You could disable juju by stopping daemons, deleting files, etc (standard Unix things).